# Code Snippet Manager for Mac

Tags: mac, file-management, source-code

What is the best code snippet manager for OS X?

I don't mind paying so if there are really good ones that you have to pay for then I dont mind.

I have heard of Snippet and Code Collector Pro.

Are there any others worth considering?

I specifically want a code manager - not a general notes manager - which is why I started a new question as I couldnt find a question that covers a manager specifically for code.

Comment: This question is subjective and argumentative. "The best". Try editing your question (e.g. specific requirements, like hotkey accessibility, Programming languages support, or AppleScriptability) so it can be answered.

Comment: There is also [Snippets](http://www.snippetsapp.com/).

Comment: Also, regarding the "answer" by Zdaxxy: You specifically want Mac OS X desktop software, no web app?

Comment: yes specifically Desktop software. cos if im on the move and dont have web access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Code Barrel might be what you are looking for. You can check it out at [CODEBARREL.COM](http://www.codebarrel.com)

There are free and paid versions depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Daniel, instead of complaining about posters articulation, how about contributing to the post in a positive manner. Oh and I failed to see in the post where it specifically excluded web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Snip2Code - http://www.snip2code.com.

It allows the user to collect, organize and share code snippets, from the web site as well as through the native apps for Mac OS X, or directly within the preferred IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Notepad++).

Check it out!